# How to Host mail using java api?

Tags: java, email, jsp

i want to host mail on my machine.So i can able to send and received mails through my machines.

is there any api in java to do the same..

thanx

Answer (score 2):

There are Java APIs to send mail through existing mail servers (see the [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/) library). As for an actual *mail server* written in Java, you should perhaps look at the [Apache James project](http://james.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

A couple additional java mail servers:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmailsrv/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ichabod/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the DeveloperWorks [Introduction to Apache James](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-james1.html) series (part one linked).